# Why does sbt create layers of projects and src in IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am new to `SBT` and trying to build a project. My `Build.scala` looks like

```
  lazy val ec = project.in(file("."))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(name := "ec")
    .aggregate(ahka, currentLogProcessor, main)

  lazy val currentLogProcessor = project.in(file("currentLogProcessor"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(name := "currentlogprocessor")
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies += "com.myorg.util" % "LP" % "0.18.0-SNAPSHOT" % "provided"
    )

  lazy val main = project
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(name := "main")
```

When `SBT` refreshes in `IntelliJ`, I see following

As you could see, even if the settings looks same for `currentLogProcessor` and `main`, the project structure is very very different.

`project` inside `currentLogProcessor` looks good but `project` under `main` is layer with `project` and `src`

What is the issue here? How can I remove the layers of project inside project?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: You mention Build.scala but syntax presented is for build.sbt, that is probably the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your projects **ec** and **main** share the same folder. Remove **main** or **ec**, or change "*in file*" for one of them.

```
lazy val main = project in file("another_path") ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @ka4eli is correct, but I'd like to point out few issues with the build definition that can make understanding it so much painful.

#### Defining top-level aggregate project

```
lazy val ec = project.in(file("."))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(name := "ec")
    .aggregate(ahka, currentLogProcessor, main)
```

You don't need it whatsoever as it's defined automatically anyway - you're just repeating what sbt does implicitly. Just remove it from the build and add `build.sbt` with the following:

```
commonSettings
```

#### Use build.sbt for a project's build definition

```
lazy val currentLogProcessor = project.in(file("currentLogProcessor"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(name := "currentlogprocessor")
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies += "com.myorg.util" % "LP" % "0.18.0-SNAPSHOT" % "provided"
    )
```

By default, `lazy val`'s name is used to call a project `project` macro should point to, i.e. no need for `in(file("currentLogProcessor"))`. The same applies to the `name` setting - you're using all-lowercase name that may or may not be needed.

Use `build.sbt` under `currentLogProcessor` directory to have the same effect:

```
name := "currentlogprocessor"
commonSettings

libraryDependencies += "com.myorg.util" % "LP" % "0.18.0-SNAPSHOT" % "provided"
```

It's that simple.

Apply the rules to the `main` project.

Have fun with sbt = it's so simple that people hardly accept it and mess up build definitions on purpose to claim otherwise :)